# jquery find dd or dt elements with text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to add a class to a `dl` element based on its dd text contents. My goal is that if the `dd` with `productView-info-value` class has the text "No" in it, I want to add a class to its entire line (so I can hide the line) - or I can remove() - but I can't seem to get the parent `dl` from the `dd`.

```
<dl class="productView-info">
    <dt class="productView-info-name">
        title of YAY SHOW ME
    </dt>
    <dd class="productView-info-value">
        YAY SHOW ME
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="productView-info">
    <dt class="productView-info-name">
            Titl of NO HIDE ME
    </dt>
    <dd class="productView-info-value">
        No
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="productView-info">
    <dt class="productView-info-name">
        Title of NO HIDE ME TOO
    </dt>
    <dd class="productView-info-value">
        No
    </dd>
</dl>
```

And here's what I've tried with jquery:

```
$('dd').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "No";  //have to trim whitespace!
}).closest('dl')
  .addClass('prod-modal-noshow');
```

I've also tried `$('dd','.productView-info-value')` with filter but that doesn't work either. I'd greatly appreciate some direction, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a jQuery object with more that one element you can use the `$.each` function to iterate over them.

```js
$('dd').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "No";
  } //have to trim whitespace!
).each( function( ind, obj ) {
  $( obj ).closest('dl').addClass('prod-modal-noshow');
});
```

```css
.prod-modal-noshow {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="productView-info">
  <dt class="productView-info-name">
                            title of YAY SHOW ME
                        </dt>
  <dd class="productView-info-value">
    YAY SHOW ME
  </dd>

</dl>
<dl class="productView-info">
  <dt class="productView-info-name">
                           Titl of NO HIDE ME
                        </dt>
  <dd class="productView-info-value">
    No
  </dd>

</dl>
<dl class="productView-info">
  <dt class="productView-info-name">
                            Title of NO HIDE ME TOO
                        </dt>
  <dd class="productView-info-value">
    No
  </dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: thanks! that's cool! can you tell me what the function( ind, obj ) does?

Comment: Yeah, that is the signature for the callback function expected by http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ which is an index and an object.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this worked for me:

```
$('dd').filter(function()
{return $.trim($(this).html()) === "No";}  //have to trim whitespace!
).parent('dl').addClass('prod-modal-noshow');\
```

If you want you can add `.remove()` and it will remove the entire `<dl>`

Also works if you swap `html()` for `text()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah the only difference is she grab's the closest `<dl>` whereas I am grabbing the `parent` for certain.